# object does not support property or method matches react-responsive-modal in IE11 with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, browser, modal-dialog

I want to open my modal popup with 'react js' in IE browser, I can understand after study some blog for IE, I have to add 'react-app-polyfill' along with import statement in a very first file that is in my index.js.
for this I am following  the below github url.
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md

but what is happening, my react js app is working fine in IE browser. but I am facing problem in my modal opening part. for modal I am using react-responsive-modal(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-modal), it is working as expected in Chrome browser but not in IE.

I am getting error when I am opening modal in IE browser. I am attaching my error screen shot.[image]

Please help if anyone can help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I try to test the issue in the IE 11 and also try to check the error messages from the picture you had posted in the original post.

From the error message, it looks like the error comes from the react-responsive-modal library files.

It looks like the [repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method is not supported in the IE browser.

So it is creating compatibility issues with the IE browser.

I suggest you try to use the library that is compatible with the IE browser or if that is not possible then you can try to identify the IE browser using JS code and inform the user to use the compatible browser with your app.